# Encontrar uma valor ( da string ) em um array PHP

Tags: php, array, string

Estou com problemas encontrar um valor variável dentro de um array
Exemplo:
Tenho as informações abaixo em alguns array.

```
$dadosCli1 = array("cep:'000000'", "cidade: 'sao paulo'", "rg: '00.000.000.-00'", "estado: 'sp'");

$dadosCli2 = array("rg:'00.000.000.-00'", "cidade: 'sao paulo'", "cep: '0000000'", "estado: 'sp'");
```

E assim sucessivamente, os dados dos clientes estão desordenados dentro dos arrays, porém preciso das informações cartas, independente das posições delas dentro do array.
Estou iniciando no php agora.

Answer (score 2):

Você ode formatar esse array para acessas as chaves diretamente. Da forma que estão seus valores você ainda vai ter que formatar os valores.

```
$dadosCli1 = array("cep:'000000'", "cidade: 'sao paulo'", "rg: '00.000.000.-00'", "estado: 'sp'");
foreach( $dadosCli1 as $key => $val )
{
    list( $key1 , $val1 ) = explode( ':' , $val );
    $arr[ trim( $key1 ) ] = trim( $val1 );
}
```

Basicamente ele vai fazer um loop no array e usando explode separar a key do val para poder acessar...

O resultado fica:

```
Array
(
    [cep] => '000000'
    [cidade] => 'sao paulo'
    [rg] => '00.000.000.-00'
    [estado] => 'sp'
)
```

Basta usar `$arr['cep']` que você obtém o valor correto

---

Como sugestão do @Guilherme Nascimento;
Você pode usar `limit`

> Se limit é definido, o array retornado irá conter o máximo de
> elementos igual a limit com o último elemento contendo o resto da
> string.

Mais sobre [explode](https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.explode.php)

Comment: Use no terceiro parâmetro do explode o valor 2 (ex: `explode(':', $val, 2)`), para evitar que divida a string em mais pedaços, acaso exista um ":" dentro de algo, por exemplo `"'foo':'bar:baz'"`... claro que no código atual do autor parece dispensável, mas não dá para ter certeza né :)

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento fiquei em dúvida se a resposta seria um paliativo ou uma gambiarra pra solução do problema rs. Sua sugestão fecha todas as pontas soltas rsrsrs []'s

Answer (score 1):

Considerando os dados nesse formato, você pode criar uma função para padronizar a saída.

```
$dadosCli1 = array("cep:'000000'", "cidade: 'sao paulo'", "rg: '00.000.000.-00'", "estado: 'sp'");

function organiza_dados(array $cliente){

    $dados_organizados = array();
    foreach($cliente as $dado){
        $e = explode(' :', $dado);
        $dados_organizados[$e[0]] = $e[1];
    }
    return $dadod_organizados;
}
```

Aí na hora de organizar é só aplicar a função.

```
$cliente = organiza_dados($dadosCli1);
```

Sendo assim os dados serão acessíveis via `$cliente["cep"]`, por exemplo.

Answer (score 0):

tudo bem?
Para acessar um valor específico em um @rray você deve passar a chave que deseja de alguma forma. Já que os dados estão desordenados, você deve passar o nome da chave que você quer retornar da seguinte forma:

```
$dadosCli1 = array("cep" => "000000", "cidade" => "sao paulo", "rg" => "00.000.000.-00", "estado" => "sp");
echo $dadosCli1['cidade'];
```

Note que precisei alterar a forma como os dados estão no array, indicando que o primeiro dado é a chave e o segundo o conteúdo.

Para saber mais sobre arrays, consulte a documentação oficial em: https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/language.types.array.php

Comment: excelente solução, adaptei o seu modelo para solucionar o problema.

Answer (score 0):

Além das abordagens imperativas apresentadas nas outras respostas, também é possível utilizar de uma abordagem funcional utilizando a função [`array_reduce()`](https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.array-reduce.php), que reduz um array para um único valor através de um processo iterativo via função callback, nesse caso [explodindo](https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.explode.php) cada elemento do array original e recombinando os fragmentos num array associativo.
Outra forma é com `array_reduce()` dividindo o array original em dois, um contendo as chaves o outro os valores, e os combinar num array associativo com a função [`array_combine`](https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.array-combine.php).

```
<?php

$dadosCli1 = array("cep:'000000'", "cidade: 'sao paulo'", "rg: '00.000.000.-00'", "estado: 'sp'");

$dadosCli2 = array("rg:'11.111.111.-11'", "cidade: 'campo grande'", "cep: '0000000'", "estado: 'ms'");


$res1 = array_reduce($dadosCli1, function($c, $i){
  $v = explode(':', $i, 2);
  $c[$v[0]] = $v[1];
  return $c;
}, []);

$res2 = array_combine(...array_reduce($dadosCli2, function($c, $i){
  $v = explode(':', $i, 2);
  $c[0][] = $v[0];
  $c[1][] = $v[1];
  return $c;  
}, [[],[]]));


echo $res1["cidade"];   //'sao paulo'
echo $res2["cidade"];   //'campo grande'
```

<sup>Teste o código no [Repl.it](https://replit.com/@RonaldoVasques/Find#main.php)</sup>

As soluções acima na forma de função:

```
function f1($arr){
  return array_reduce($arr, function($c, $i){
    $v = explode(':', $i, 2);
    $c[$v[0]] = $v[1];
    return $c;
  }, []);
}

function f2($arr){
  return array_combine(...array_reduce($arr, function($c, $i){
    $v = explode(':', $i, 2);
    $c[0][] = $v[0];
    $c[1][] = $v[1];
    return $c;  
  }, [[],[]]));
}
```

Comment: O mesmo que disse ao @PapaCharlie: Use no terceiro parâmetro do explode o valor 2 (ex: `explode(':', $val, 2)`), para evitar que divida a string em mais pedaços, acaso exista um ":" dentro de algo, por exemplo `"'foo':'bar:baz'"`... claro que no código atual do autor parece dispensável, mas não dá para ter certeza né :)